# Can I have alcohol in my luggage bag while on transfer in Doha Airport?

Tags: airports, alcohol, qatar, doha

My wife and I are flying from Australia to Georgia and we have 1 stop in Doha. We're taking some alcohol with us; but my wife panicked and asked me if it's illegal to have alcohol anywhere in the bags or luggage.

I know that its a neutral zone once you are only in the airport and not leave.

Comment: Related [question](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/37959/does-the-new-doha-hamad-international-still-offer-alcoholic-left-luggage-and)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are transferring i.e. not arriving or departing from Hamad Intl. Airport; you are allowed to carry alcohol with you. The limit is 5 ltr. per person.

You will not be allowed to leave the airport with the alcohol.

Please read

> As a transfer passenger you may carry alcoholic beverages in your
>   baggage. However these must be packed in containers of less than 5
>   litres.
>
> Please note if you intend to exit the airport and visit Qatar before
>   continuing your journey, then alcoholic beverages cannot be brought
>   into the country under any circumstances. These will be confiscated
>   and you won’t be able to retrieve them at any time.
>
> If you’re travelling to Australia and have purchased alcoholic
>   beverages or cosmetics from an airport other than Hamad International
>   Airport, then these will be confiscated at your onward flight’s
>   boarding gate. This procedure is in accordance with Australian
>   regulations.

source : http://dohahamadairport.com/airport-guide/at-the-airport/security-customs

So you're allowed a total of 10 liters of the beverage (5 you, 5 your wife) during transit.

Comment: It says the containers must be less than 5l. It doesn't say anything about how much you're allowed to carry on that page.